# Does spring always create a new IOC container for each new client if not then how does it manage the singleton beans?

Tags: java, spring

Does spring always create a new IOC container for each new client if not then how does it manage the singleton beans? I'm really confused that how does one singleton bean managed requests from different users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It will not create new IOC container for each new client. That's why bean scope is there. If you want to keep bean per request you can use request as bean scope. Singleton is not thread safe. So each new request, it will share the instance properties.

**Request scope definition from documentation**

> Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a single HTTP
>   request; that is each and every HTTP request will have its own
>   instance of a bean created off the back of a single bean definition.
>   Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can you please tell then how does it manage the request from different users at one time? just like in my controller one user passed some value and at the same time, another user will update that value.

Comment: You can use singletons. But it is not thread safe and lead to error conditions.